# Unable to hit breakpoints outside of Laravel's index.php

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I work on Linux (Archlinux) with Laravel v5.6.7, php/php-fpm v7.2.3, nginx v1.12.2 and xdebug v2.6.0.

My web site run locally.
I installed the add-on Xdebug helper for Firefox.

I manage to configure Xdebug, PhpStorm to hit breakpoints on the `index.php` file and it works. But neither of the other breakpoints (outside of index.php) are hit, I put some in Controllers and in Models.

If I use `xdebug_break()` in Controllers or Models the execution stop well on the next code line.

I also tried with VS Code, and I have the same problem.

Does anyone manage to debug Controllers or Models php code in a Laravel project?

Here are my settings:

**xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9123
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

**PhpStorm:**

- Xdebug port: 9123
- no mapping configured, because my nginx server runs locally

**Edit:**
I tried on Windows with WAMP v3.1.0, PHP v7.1.9, Xdebug v2.5.5, Phpstorm and VScode. Unfortunately I have the same behavior as on Linux.
Here are screenshots of breakpoints and settings:
[image: Breakpoints list]
[image: Working breakpoint on index.php]
[image: Breakpoint in route]
[image: Breakpoint in Controller]
[image: Breakpoint in Model]
[image: Phpstorm settings - PHP]
[image: Phpstorm settings - PHP - CLI]
[image: Phpstorm settings - PHP - Debug1]
[image: Phpstorm settings - PHP - Debug2]
[image: Phpstorm settings - Run-Debug Config]
[image: Phpstorm settings - PHP - Servers]

Comment: Please provide screenshots (how you debug; where breakpoints are etc) or better screencast, xdebug log as well. I have no problems with debugging local Laravel projects (PHP 7.0-7.2; Xdebug 2.6; IIS; Windows 10; PhpStorm) -- be it CLI command (artisan) or a web page. Must be some settings or the way how you are trying to debug.

Comment: I have done that with PHPstorm and Apache server, the only place I know you can't use breakpoints and have to use `xdebug_break()` is on blade views but it makes sense since is not the view but the compiled file that is executed.

Comment: The PhpStorm screenshot says you're using port 9000, not port 9123. Is that intended? Also, is the PhpStorm project located in the web root, or it's a different directory?

Comment: Also, try setting breakpoints on lines actually having some statements - Xdebug won't stop at a line with brace only.

Comment: Just what Eugene Morozov have said. The xdebug port might be OK since it's another computer/OS and it's all local (so no need to change xdebug port because of php-pfm). But breakpoints -- only first one is OK (safe). Others most likely will not be hit at all (due to the way how PHP generates byte code and where xdebug can break).

Comment: @Eugene thanks a lot, I moved my breakpoint from a line containing a curly bracket to a line with a real statement and it works !!!

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for comments, it really helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Visual Studio and C#, it is not possible to add breakpoints on curly brackets.
Nothing in the IDE warns about it, but those breakpoints are never hit.
Just move them to the next line, with a real statement make them hittable.